# three.js how to allow OrbitControls to rotate around object with a static buffer geometry creating 3D spirograph effect

Tags: three.js, 3d

I am trying to create a 3d spirograph effect. In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wilco_/r0uj85n6/21/) I have a simple Points plane rotating. When you press the Enter key a transparent plane material is added in front of the camera creating a trailing effect. This is all working as intended, but I was hoping to be able to add OrbitControls to be able to rotate around the spirograph as a whole without the trailing effect created by the transparent plane being affected by the OrbitControls as well.

```
var fadeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x000000,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.01
  });
var fadePlane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10);
var fadeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(fadePlane, fadeMaterial);
  
    fadeMesh.position.z = -0.08;
    fadeMesh.renderOrder = -1;
  
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

  camera.add(fadeMesh);
  camera.position.z = 60;
```

The image below shows the effect from a static viewpoint (before moving the camera with OrbitControls), but as soon as I move the camera the trailing effect is also affected. Essentially I would like to be able to rotate around this without the trailing effect changing.

[image: spiro]

I think the issue is caused by the transparent plane being in front of the camera, but I'm not sure how else to create the trailing effect. Any advice on how to create this while being able to rotate around it without disturbing the trailing effect?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with your approach. You're essentially rendering 24 points onto the canvas at a time, and the reason they stay visible on your canvas is because you're using `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` on your renderer. Now when you're trying to move the camera, those previous points have already been painted to the canvas but they no longer exist in 3D space. It's similar to painting with ink; once you've painted a dot, you can't re-position it.

If you want to be able to orbit the camera while maintaining the spirograph look, you'd need to re-think you approach, and not preserve the drawing buffer. I think you'd need to add 24 new points on each frame, so they always exist in 3D space. Your geometry would need to grow in quantity from 24, 48, 72, 96, 120, 144, etc...